# Can I change appearance of Drop Down List on hover

Tags: css, asp.net

Is it possible to change the appearance of an asp:DropDownList on hover? For example - if you visit Nordstrom's website and select a category (men > boots), you'll see a list of options to narrow your boot preference. When you hover over an option, the top border goes from thin to thick. I *really* love the subtlety of this. I've managed to style my DDL similarly, but I can't figure out the hover.

current style:

```
.DDL {
    margin-right: 1%;
    width: 18%;
    min-width:150px;
    padding-bottom:2em;
    padding-top:1em;
}
select.DDL {
    border-style: solid none none none;
    border-top-color: #C0C0C0;
    border-top-width: thin;
}
```

I have tried

```
select.DDL option:checked,
select.DDL option:hover {
    border-top-width:thick;
}
```

and

```
select.DDL:focus > option:checked { 
    border-top-width:thick;
}
```

but neither worked.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Those aren't `select` or `option` elements on Nordstrom's website.  If you want to replicate what they're doing, take a look at their HTML/CSS.

Comment: Thank you. I'm a rabbit in a hole, but I cannot find the destination... (sorry, long project, late nights, bad reference). I've been through their style sheets, but cannot, for the life of me, figure out where they are specifying this. I was hoping it was an element.